# Onclick rotation (animation) not happening

Tags: jquery, rotation, jquery-animate

I have a question about a little problem that I am having, which I have sketched here: http://jsfiddle.net/gm3mG/1/

I want to rotate the arrow which is in `<span id="rotator">`, but I can't make it work. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

My second question: how can I make it to rotate the arrow back after 1 second after it is clicked?

Comment: Here ya go -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gm3mG/19/) ...

Comment: Thanks adeneo. Can you check my second question too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're using jQuery, not Mootools, so you have to configure jsFiddle accordingly (look at the `Choose Framework` section in the left pane).

Second, CSS transforms do not work with inline elements, and `<span>` elements are inline by default. Styling it with `display: inline-block` solves your problem.

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gm3mG/16/).

**EDIT:** Concerning the second part of your question, the canonical answer is to use [window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout). However, you can also use jQuery animation facilities like [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to achieve the same effect:

```
$("#rotator").addClass("lol").delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).removeClass("lol");
    next();
});
```

You can test this solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gm3mG/23/).

Comment: Thank you man! The only problem is that Google Chrome don't let it rotate. Anyway, I have accepted your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The [`transform` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120911/#transform-property) only applies to [transformable elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120911/#TermTransformableElement), which your `<span>` is not one of.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by making sure the .lol class works first.  Just apply it to the span#rotator  to start with.  I tried in the fiddle and its not working to start with, not to mention javascript to dynamically add the class to it...